# Why is Linq-to-Entities recognizing query in query, but not when query is returned from a method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

This is a common error I've found, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ProjectX.Models.DTOs.ExampleDTOUDC] Select(Int32)'
 method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Here is the offending code in question.

```
    public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> Select()
    {
        return from e in db.vw_Example
                   select new ExampleDTO()
                   {

                       exampleUDCs =  new ExampleUDCRepository().Select(v.VehicleID).AsEnumerable()
                       //etc


                   };
    }
```

and the ExampleUDCRepository.Select() method is:

```
  public IQueryable<ExampleUDCDTO> Select(int id)
  {
        return from eudc in db.ExampleUDCs
               where eudc.ExampleID == id
               select new ExampleUDCDTO()
               {
                   ExampleID = eudc.ExampleID,
                   //etc
               };
   }
```

I understand why Linq needs everything to be in a form it can be turned into an SQL query, but what I don't understand is why this works I take that same query from the first `Select()` method and do something like:

```
        public IQueryable<ExampleDTO> Select()
    {
        return from e in db.vw_Example
                   select new ExampleDTO()
                   {    
                       ExampleID = e.ExampleID,
                       ExampleUDCs =  (from eudc in db.ExampleUDCs
                                      where eudc.ExampleID == id
                                      select new ExampleUDCDTO()
                                      {
                                           ExampleID = eudc.ExampleID
                                           //etc
                                      })


                   };
    }
```

In case you wanted to see it, here is the ExampleUDCs declaration in my ExampleDTO class:

```
public IEnumerable<ExampleUDCDTO> ExampleUDCs { get; set; }
```

Does anyone know a way for me to fix this to reuse code from my `ExampleUDCDTO().Select(int id)` method instead of putting all of the queries into the first `Select()` method?

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework works with expressions, and it tries to compile the complete expression into a piece of SQL. Since you are creating an expression with a method call in it, EF tries to compile that method call into SQL as well. And that is not possible.